# Как зафиксировать и увеличить aside при скроллинге?

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Всем привет! помогите пожалуйста, нужно чтобы при скроллинге вниз шапка пропадала, а боковая панель aside, наоборот поднималась ещё выше и фиксировалась к верхней границе сайта

Сразу говорю: position: sticky мне не подходит, так как мне нужно, чтобы при скроллинге вниз боковая панель увеличивала свою высоту

[вот пример без javascript](https://goo.su/HnU07C)